# How can I save an image with PIL without increasing the size?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image1.jpg")
im.save( "image2.jpg", quality=100 , optimize=True )



image1.jpg=2592KB
image2.jpg=3146KB
```

How can I save the file with Pillow and keep the same size?

Comment: Maybe the original picture didn't have 100% quality?

Comment: Saving jpeg means recompression. While retaining the size there will always be losses (it's somewhat like creating a mp3 from a mp3). There are *some* transformations which can be done lossless with jpgs but need special software.